# seven six-sided fair dice are rolled

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Seven fair six-sided dice are rolled randomly.

Given that only five of the six numbers appeared, what is the probability that the number 3 appeared?

Here is my solution, but I am unsure if it is correct.

Let A= the event that the 3 appeared, and B= the event that only five numbers appeared.

Then $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{\left(\binom{5}{4}\binom{5}{2}7!/2!2! + \binom{5}{4}\binom{5}{1}7!/3!\right)/6^7}{\left(\binom{6}{5}\binom{5}{2}7!/2!2! + \binom{6}{5}\binom{5}{1}7!/3!\right)/6^7}=\frac{5}{6}.$$

Does the final answer intuitively make sense?

Comment: It is basic courtesy in this site to upvote and accept answers. That is the only way you reward the users who took time to answer your question. You have not done so in several of your questions and neither have you given any feedback or interacted in case your query has not been answered to your full satisfaction.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know it. Henceforth, I will do. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Glad that you took the comment in the right spirit. I perhaps took a bit harsh of a tone as you are a member for 7 years and I assumed that you'll be familiar with the workings of this site quite well by now.

Comment: We all are here to learn and share what we know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use symmetry, to find this result $\frac 56$

Exactly 5 numbers appear.

It means : exactly one number is missing.

Let $k$ be this missing number.

$k$ can be 1,2,3,4,5 or 6, and all options are equiprobable (symmetry).

$P(k=1)=P(k=2)=P(k=3)=P(k=4)=P(k=5)=P(k=6)= \frac 16$

And the question was : What is $P(k \neq 3)$ ?

This probability is $1-\frac 16$

Answer (score 1):

(**Note**: this assumes that exactly 5 of the 6 numbers appear)

Consider all dice rolls where 5 different numbers appear. We can put all possible outcomes in groups of $6$, so that for every outcome, cyclically permuting the numbers on each die ($1\to2\to\ldots\to6\to1$) gives us a different outcome in the same group. These $6$ outcomes are indeed different, since they're missing a different number.

Out of every group, exactly $5$ outcomes roll a $3$. It's equally likely for an outcome to belong to any of these groups, giving a probability of $5/6$.

If you happen to be familiar with group theory, you'll recognize this idea as [orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers) from a group action.

Comment: Both are valid approaches. Not sure where the confusion lies.

Comment: I see now, sorry for the previous comment.